# Android studio room database - not returning values in onRestart() method

Tags: android-studio, android-room

My app is a list of element names. Clicking one goes to another activity with more details, and an editText and button to change its name. When I go back to the list, I want it to have the new name if updated. My onCreate method has this code which populates it from the database perfectly (ignore the hardcoded size, its just simpler for debugging)

```
        final String DATABASE_NAME = "element_db";
        final AppDatabase appDatabase;
        appDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME).build();

        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        final String[] element = new String[3];
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                List<Element> elements;
                elements = appDatabase.elementDao().fetchElements(); // a dao query "select*from"
                int size = elements.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                    element[i] = elements.get(i).getName();
                }
            }
        }) .start();
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_list_view, R.id.textView, element);
        list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, itemdetail.class);
                i.putExtra("pos", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

To achieve an updated list when returning to this screen, I copied the above code into the onRestart method, but now the database does not return anything. If I just set the array that goes into the adapter to {"a", "a", "a"} the list populates fine. Any ideas why the database works onCreate but not onRestart?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ViewModel and livedata to observe any database  change